# Is there a way to retrieve the vectors selected by fcoalesce?

Tags: r, data.table

When using `fcoalesce`, is there any way I can retrieve the indices or names of the selected vectors?

Here is a simplified two-vector example, for the following coalesce of vectors a and b:

```
library(data.table)
a = c(NA,2,3,4,NA)
b = c(1,3,3,4,5)
fcoalesce(a,b)
 
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

I'd like to see something like this:

```
b,a,a,a,b
```

A real life example could have any number of vectors.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `ifelse` - `coalesce` is simply taking the first non-NA for each row/element between two vectors/columns.  Thus, create a logical condition for `NA` elements, and specify the 'yes', 'no' as the object names

```
ifelse(is.na(a), 'b', 'a')
[1] "b" "a" "a" "a" "b"
```

Comment: True, but the given example is simplified. Let's say I have 500 columns instead of two.

Comment: @Cos Maybe you need `names(dt_combined)[max.col(!is.na(dt_combined), 'first')]`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it by merging all vectors into a data.table (dt_combined) and coalescing them iteratively:

```
apply(dt_combined, 1, function(i){
  (1:length(dt_combined))[ which(!is.na(i))[1] ]
})
```

One could also get the column names instead of the column index:

```
apply(dt_combined, 1, function(i){
  colnames(dt_combined)[ which(!is.na(i))[1] ]
})
```